# Exchange 2003 Corrupt Inbox

Tags: exchange-2003

Using Exchange 2003, Outlook 2003.

The user’s mailbox is stored on the server, and everything appears to be working fine.  The inbox and all sub folders are accessible.  The problem presents itself when the user’s mailbox is exported to a PST.  Outlook gives the message ‘Operation failed’.  Loading exmerge on the exchange server, a PST file is created, but exmerge and outlook tell me the PST is corrupt.  ScanPST also reports the PST from exmerge is corrupt.

I’m thinking about manually creating a PST in Outlook, and then manually copying the contents into the PST.  Before I do, does anyone know of a way to scan a Mailbox to find and remove the corrupted items which I assume is the issue.

Background: 
1.  I’d prefer not to do any low level eseutils commands on the store.
2.  This is part of a DR scenario, which is why I’m trying export the data to a PST file.

Comment: How large is the .pst? Doesn't outlook/exchange balk at anything over 2GB ( or is that old info)?

Comment: The file was around 2GB, but I don't think that was it. I manually copied each folder to a new PST, and it stopped half way through. I tried to copy the messages it stopped on (an NDR message the user saved) and it didn't work. I delete that message, and everything copied over fine. 

I can't be sure, but I think that one particular message was corrupt and permanently deleting it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is the PST larger than 2 GB? It is the limit using Exmerge, I'm afraid.

There a two things you could do:

- export the mailbox to a .pst file by using Outlook instead of the ExMerge tool
- use ExMerge to export individual folders or groups of folders from the mailbox into individual smaller .pst files instead of exporting the whole mailbox to a single large .pst file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools you can use to repair an individual mailbox, expecially if you can connect to the account with outlook and access the mailbox from there. [This article](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Troubleshooting_and_repairing_mailboxes_and_databases.html) documents a number of ways to do so.

If you can connect with outlook you can always try exporting to a PST from inside outlook, and only exporting certain folders to try and locate the corrupt mail. It may be that its in the deleted item folder and can be ignored.